# Groovy way to selectively mixin methods from multiple classes

Tags: groovy, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I'm writing a Groovy script based on commons-io that monitors some source directory and synchronizes its files with some destination directory.

```
@Grab(group='commons-io', module='commons-io', version='2.4')
import org.apache.commons.io.monitor.*
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
class BaseSynchronizedFileListener extends FileAlterationListenerAdaptor {
    def srcDir
    def destDir   
    /* Given a source file, returns the destination file */
    File destination(File file) {
        new File(destDir, file.getAbsolutePath() - srcDir.getAbsolutePath())
    }
}
class CopyOnWriteListener extends BaseSynchronizedFileListener {
    @Override 
    void onFileChange(File file) {
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, destination(file))
    }
    @Override
    void onFileCreate(File file) { 
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, destination(file))
    } 
}
class DeleteOnDeleteListener extends BaseSynchronizedFileListener {
    @Override
    void onFileDelete(File file) {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(destination(file))
    }
}
```

In addition to straight file copies, I want to support Less->CSS compilation, wherein `.less` files in the source directory are synchronized with `.css` files in the destination directory.

```
@Grab(group='org.lesscss', module='lesscss', version='1.3.3')
import org.lesscss.LessCompiler
class CompileLessOnWriteListener extends BaseSynchronizedFileListener {
    def compiler = new LessCompiler()
    @Override
    File destination(File file) {
        File dest = super.destination(file)
        new File(dest.parentFile, dest.name - '.less' + '.css')
    }
    void compile(File less) {
        compiler.compile(less, destination(less))
    }
    @Override
    void onFileChange(File less) {
        compile(less)
    }
    @Override
    void onFileCreate(File less) { 
        compile(less)
    } 
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is when I attempt to create class `DeleteCssOnDeleteLessListener` to handle the situation when `.less` files are deleted (which, in turn, deletes the corresponding `.css` file) -- the code I need to do this exists in two different inheritance trees.

- `CompileLessOnWriteListener` contains the `destination()` method
- `DeleteOnDeleteListener` contains the `onFileDelete()` method to delete the CSS file returned by the `destination()` method

**Is there a "Groovy way" to selectively mixin or inherit methods from both of these classes into a new class?**

Or do I just need to bite the bullet and create a common super class for `CompileLessOnWriteListener` and `DeleteCssOnDeleteLessListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very "Groovy", in my opinion, nor very efficient looking, but at least this approach solves my problem without having to create a common superclass:

```
class DeleteCssOnDeleteLessListener extends DeleteOnDeleteListener {
    @Override
    File destination(File f) {
        new CompileLessOnWriteListener(destDir: this.destDir, srcDir: this.srcDir).destination(f)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Changed the implementation. Lets see if i got the idea. You need:

- Inherit two methods
- "Inherit" constructor
- It needs to be an instance of an interface

I think a heavy metaprogramming helps here. We can declare two objects to `DeleteCssOnDeleteLessListener` delegate methods to, and these objects will be accessing properties from it.

For the interface, i think you are better using the `as Interface` operator.

Dynamically "inherit" the constructors may get tricky. Since it is only two properties, i've declared them. You can delegate the `getProperty`/`setProperty` to one of the other two objects, if you prefer DRYing your code:

```
class DeleteCssOnDeleteLessListener {
  def destDir, srcDir
  def onLessDelete(file) {
    onFileDelete destination( file )
  }
}

class CompileLessOnWriteListener {
  def destination(file) {
    "destination $file from $srcDir"
  }
}

class DeleteOnDeleteListener {
  def onFileDelete(file) {
    "onFileDelete $file and $destDir"
  }
}

def delete = new DeleteCssOnDeleteLessListener(destDir: "dest/dir", srcDir: "src/dir")
def compileLess = new CompileLessOnWriteListener()
def deleteOnDelete = new DeleteOnDeleteListener()

delete.metaClass {
  destination = compileLess.&destination
  onFileDelete = deleteOnDelete.&onFileDelete
}

compileLess.metaClass.getProperty = { property -> delete.getProperty property }
deleteOnDelete.metaClass.getProperty = { property -> delete.getProperty property }

assert delete.onLessDelete("style.less") == "onFileDelete destination style.less from src/dir and dest/dir"
```

Comment: Not quite. First of all, I lose the ability to set srcDir and destDir properties upon initialization, e.g `(new DeleteCssOnDeleteLessWriter(srcDir: s, destDir: d)`. Secondly, I need to have DeleteCssOnDeleteLessWriter be an instance of FileAlterationListener. I can't do this by implementing the interface, sadly, although I can do it dynamically: `observer.addListener(delCssListener as FileAlterationListener)`. Finally, the mixin includes the `onFileCreate` and `onFileChange` methods. All I need is the `onFileDelete`, thus the "selectively" part of the question.

Comment: What about `@Delegate`? It automagically inherits the interfaces.

Comment: could I selectively `@Delegate`?

Comment: I had missed the notification that you had edited your answer. Let me try it out and I'll get back to you. It looks promising.

Comment: Wow, i didn't remembered this one :-)